# Just getting values from pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to be able to just access the values in a row in a pandas data frame without all the additional metadata. For example, when I get the 0th row of the color column, I would like to just get "green." However, when I use `loc[0]` I get additional metadata:

```
color    green
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Is there any way to get rid the metadata?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show more in detail what you have already tried and what you exactly want. Right now, this looks like an unwelcome type of question: One where ops have put minimal effort into reading the documentation or trying stuff out themselves and just ask straight away for code. This is not typical behavior of professionals or enthusiastic programmers, for whom this site is intended.

Comment: See additional information in the 10 minutes for pandas, which also includes the answer to your question at the direct link: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html#getting

Comment: What you are seeing is just pretty output, why should this matter? It doesn't affect any operations where you perform operations on the this data selection

Answer (score 0):

Something like `df.loc[0, 'color']` should work.